# How can I get parameters in twig?

Tags: templating

I wrote a PHP script to deploy data to live-cdn and included a "deploy" button on the dashboard. the script returns ?success=true, and i need to show div element with "Congratulations"

i tried this with no success:

```
{% if app.request.query.get('success') %}
  <div>
    Glückwunsch! Deployment läuft.
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
{% if craft.request.getQueryString('success') %}
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getQueryString

Answer (score 11):

Actually, reading from the [**Craft 2** docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/craft.request.html#methods) it's:

```
craft.request.getQueryString()      // returns the whole query string
craft.request.getQuery('success')   // returns only the value of 'success'
```

Comment: Thank you, Antoine, that was helpful. And in Craft 3 it seems to now be `craft.app.request.getQueryParam()` otherwise a deprecation error.

Comment: @kr37 Cool! I suggest you turn your comment into a standalone answer, that would be helpful for Craft 3 users. I updated my answer to indicate that it applies to Craft 2.

Answer (score 3):

As @kr37 pointed out in the comments to another answer, the method for Craft 3, and now 4, is [`craft.app.request.getQueryParam()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220518223359/https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-web-request.html#method-getqueryparam)

```
{# get $_GET['foo'], if it exists #}
{% set foo = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('foo') %}

{# get $_GET['foo']['bar'], if it exists #}
{% set bar = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('foo.bar') %}
```